macOS Jenkins Agent connection breaks when I log in
I have a Jenkins agent on my Mac running as a LaunchDaemon:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>jenkins-agent</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>myUser</string>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/jenkins/</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/jenkins/agent.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/jenkins/agent.log</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>/usr/local/var/jenkins/startAgent.sh</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

On macOS 14 this was working perfectly fine.
But Since I updated to macOS 15 (more specifically 15.0.1) there is some weird behavior happening:
When I restart the Mac and before I log in with my user to macOS, the agent works fine. I can see that it is connected to Jenkins in the Web UI.
But as soon as I log in with my user to macOS, the agent connection breaks.
Oct 31, 2024 9:56:48 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Oct 31, 2024 10:07:42 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
Oct 31, 2024 10:07:52 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver waitForReady
INFO: Failed to connect to the controller. Will try again: java.net.ConnectException No route to host (connect failed)

Did anyone experience a similar issue and maybe knows how to fix it?
